# PHP Script wipes strings completely - how to fix?

Tags: php, html

[image]

---

I have made a script which saves a few lines of PHP to a `.php` file. All my scripts work perfectly fine, but just this page is starting to get annoying.

Explaination of what is happening in the GIF:

**1:** I change the settings - the last 2 settings need to appear when you enable the 2nd setting called "Custom style". That works fine and all.
**2:** So you enable it and for some reason it completely wipes the other 2 settings (the "primarycolor" and "adminbg").

How can this happen? What am I doing wrong? My script is below if you want to try it out yourself.

---

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$string = '<?php 
$customoptions = '. $_POST["customoptions"] .';
$primarycolor = "'. $_POST["primarycolor"] .'";
$adminbg = "'. $_POST["adminbg"] .'";
?>';

$fp = fopen("includes/userstyle.php", "w");
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);
}

include("includes/userstyle.php");
?>
<form action="" name="customopt" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Panel language</td>
<td>
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option><?php echo $lang['chooselanguage']; ?></option>
<option value="dashboard.php?lang=en">English</option>
<option value="dashboard.php?lang=nl">Dutch</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Custom Style</td>
<td><select name="customoptions" id="customoptions"><option value="true" <?php if($customoptions == true){ echo 'selected'; }; ?>><?php echo $lang['enabled']; ?></option><option value="false" <?php if($customoptions == false){ echo 'selected'; }; ?>><?php echo $lang['disabled']; ?></option></select></td>
</tr>
<?php if($customoptions) { ?>
<tr>
<td>Primary Color</td>
<td><input name="primarycolor" type="text" id="primarycolor" value="<?php echo $primarycolor; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Background Color</td>
<td><input name="adminbg" type="text" id="adminbg" value="<?php echo $adminbg; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['ok']; ?>">
</form>
```

---

**EDIT: userstyle.php**

```
<?php 
$customoptions = true;
$primarycolor = "555";
$adminbg = "fff";
?>
```

Comment: first of all: putting unsanitized data into a database is a bad idea - but putting it into an executable php-script like that is a VERY very very very bad idea - an attacker could hijack your whole server with this very easily. you probably should ask yourself "what do i want to achieve by writing my data in a script file instead of a database?" and as follow-up question "how can i prevent myself from writing data into a script file?"

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Correct, I know that but this is a simple test, it will never go live.

Comment: if no empty $_POST['adminbg'] ?

Comment: Nice idea adding an animated gif +1 just for that

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand, but a test is a test from the localhost - no user will ever touch it nor will it ever go live.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I will update it with the userstyle.php. It's not that complex! ;)

Comment: *..If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?* This line made my day @JayBlanchard. *Great !!*

Comment: At the very least, you can `var_export` to produce *safe string literals* which won't pose any injection problem. This is necessary just to ensure you are preserving proper PHP syntax when producing PHP source code.

Comment: Back to the original question... those two fields are only output `if($customoptions)`. Where does that variable come from? Trivial explanation: it only exists under one specific circumstance and this circumstance is not given after you have submitted the form...

Comment: @deceze That's a very good answer. I haven't thought of that one!!

Comment: This is really something you need to learn to ***debug*** yourself, it's pretty simple to trace back those steps...

Answer (score 2):

When you post your form for the second time, you post empty values, and they are saved to file, as expected.

You should add something like

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST['primarycolor']) && !empty($_POST['adminbg'])) {
    // ...
```

But actually there can be another validation rules.

And as others noticed in comments — this is, even in educational purposes, very stupid idea to save user data into php file and then execute that file. The simplest alternative — save settings to a json file with `json_encode`, then decode, and don't forget to html-escape them with at least `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: This is a good starting point to solving your problem; do not write PHP with PHP.  Save your data as JSON if anything.  Then, on page load, read the data from your JSON file.  On POST, save your data to your JSON file and reload the page.  The updates should now be reflected in your page.